# Is there a way to make embedded pentaho reporting engine to use a custom Implementation of Localization Context?

Tags: java, pentaho, embedding, pentaho-data-integration, pentaho-report-designer

I am trying to learn more about the functionality of pentaho reporting in general. I was looking for a way to implement custom classes for the available interfaces in pentaho. As of now, it would really help me if I can know how do I implement and make pentaho use my own LocalizationContext clas avalable in pentaho.library.formula. It uses DefaultLocalizationContext by default.

I have tried adding an editableconfig in ClassicEngineBoot. and adding the class in libformula.properties